# Android NoClassDefFoundError - RSA Encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working on a concept project.

I have a **server and client**, both are implemented with Kryonet TCP/UDP library. It works well as pure Java on my computer, however when I try to execute some of the code on Android, it gives the following

**LogCat output:**

```
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229): Process: com.example.kryoandrochat, PID: 19229
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at com.example.kryoandrochat.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:133)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4626)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19300)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-18 15:35:40.718: E/AndroidRuntime(19229):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I included JRE System library in my project but nothing has changed.

**Here is the client code:**

```
package com.example.kryoandrochat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Client client;
    private TextView tv;
    private EditText et;
    private Button send;
    private PublicKey publicKey, targetsPublicKey;
    private String targetUserName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextView);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chatField);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

        client = new Client();
        new NetworkTask().execute("");

        client.addListener(new Listener(){

            public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {

                if(object instanceof ClientConnectedPacket){
                    ClientConnectedPacket ccp = (ClientConnectedPacket) object;
                    tv.setText(ccp.userName + " is online now. \n");
                    PublicKeyPacket pkp = new PublicKeyPacket();
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append(((RSAPublicKeyImpl) publicKey).getModulus().toString());
                    stringBuilder.append("|");
                    stringBuilder.append(((RSAPublicKeyImpl) publicKey).getPublicExponent().toString());
                    String serPK = stringBuilder.toString();
                    pkp.publicKey = serPK;
                    pkp.targetUserName = targetUserName;
                    client.sendTCP(pkp);

                } 
            }
        });     

    }

    private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                client.connect(10000, "myHostIP", 27960, 8008);

                new Thread(client).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Baglanamadik.");
            }   

            new Thread(client).start();

            return "Connected";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            tv.setText("We are connected");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            client.getKryo().register(ChatPacket.class);
            client.getKryo().register(ClientConnectedPacket.class);
            client.getKryo().register(UserConnectedPacket.class);
            client.getKryo().register(UserDisconnectedPacket.class);    
            client.getKryo().register(KeyPairGenerator.class);
            client.getKryo().register(KeyPair.class);
            client.getKryo().register(PublicKey.class);
            client.getKryo().register(PrivateKey.class);
            client.getKryo().register(PublicKeyPacket.class);
            //client.getKryo().register(sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.class);
            //client.getKryo().register(sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.class);
            //client.getKryo().register(sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.class);
            client.getKryo().register(byte[].class);
            client.getKryo().register(java.math.BigInteger.class);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == send){

            String temp = "";
            temp = et.getText().toString();
            if (!temp.equals("")){

                ChatPacket c = new ChatPacket();
                c.userName = "user3";
                c.targetUserName = targetUserName;

                PublicKeyPacket pkp = new PublicKeyPacket();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append(((RSAPublicKeyImpl) publicKey).getModulus().toString());
                stringBuilder.append("|");
                stringBuilder.append(((RSAPublicKeyImpl) publicKey).getPublicExponent().toString());
                String serPK = stringBuilder.toString();
                pkp.publicKey = serPK;
                pkp.userName = "user3";
                pkp.targetUserName = targetUserName;
                client.sendTCP(pkp);

                /*try {
                    c.message = encryptData(temp);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }*/
                client.sendTCP(c);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`import sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl;`

This is obviously nonsensical. There is no such class on Android; that means you can't use it. There might be such a class in Oracle (previously Sun) Java, but your code should *never* explicitly reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, select build path > configure build path, check the option for the library.

Comment: What do you mean with "check the option for the library"?